# When does a monad compose with a co-monad?

Tags: category-theory, monads

We know that two monads compose if there is a distributive law.  What is the law that is necessary to compose a monad and a co-monad?  When you combine a monad and co-monad, you get a (co)monad that has both monad and co-monad natural transformations.

Comment: Have you read Power and Watanabe's [_Combining a Monad and a Comonad_](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82680163.pdf)? The abstract says: "We give a systematic treatment of distributivity for a monad and a comonad as arises in giving category theoretic accounts of operational and denotational semantics", which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor neat thanks.